# Web Scraping using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my code

```
r = requests.get(base_url)
all_para = ""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
for iteri in range(len(headers)):
    deet = soup.find('h3', text = headers[iteri]) # Search for div tags of class 'entry-content content'
    for para in deet.find_next_siblings(): # Within these tags, find all p tags
        if para.name == "h2" or para.name == "h3":
            break
        elif para.name == "p":
            all_para += para.get_text()
            all_para += '\n'
```

But I am getting a error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-ed21c6e3d415> in <module>
      4 for iteri in range(len(headers)):
      5     deet = soup.find('h3', text = headers[iteri]) # Search for div tags of class 'entry-content content'
----> 6     for para in deet.find_next_siblings(): # Within these tags, find all p tags
      7         if para.name == "h2" or para.name == "h3":
      8             break

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_siblings'
```

But I don't know why I am getting this error.

Comment: Can you share URL? `deet` is `None` - so `<h3>` with the specified text couldn't be found.

Comment: @AndrejKesely https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia
It works for other articles

Comment: What information do you need to get from that page?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I am trying to write a function that can loop through the entries in headers and extract the contents of each header and then combine all the text into the variable all_para

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all `<h3>` headers and `<p>` under it you can combine `.find_next_siblings` with `.find_previous`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from textwrap import wrap

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

out = []
for h3 in soup.select("h3"):
    ps = [
        p.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
        for p in h3.find_next_siblings("p")
        if p.find_previous("h3") == h3
    ]
    if ps:
        out.append((h3.get_text(strip=True), "\n".join(ps)))

# print the headers and paragraphs:
for h, p in out:
    print(h)
    print()
    print("\n".join(wrap(p)))
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prinst:

```
Nupedia

Other collaborative online encyclopedias were attempted before
Wikipedia, but none were as successful. [15] Wikipedia began as a
complementary project for Nupedia , a free online English-language
encyclopedia project whose articles were written by experts and
reviewed under a formal process. [16] It was founded on March 9, 2000,
under the ownership of Bomis , a web portal company. Its main figures
were Bomis CEO Jimmy Wales and Larry Sanger , editor-in-chief for
Nupedia and later Wikipedia. [1] [17] Nupedia was initially licensed
under its own Nupedia Open Content License, but even before Wikipedia
was founded, Nupedia switched to the GNU Free Documentation License at
the urging of Richard Stallman . [18] Wales is credited with defining
the goal of making a publicly editable encyclopedia, [19] [20] while
Sanger is credited with the strategy of using a wiki to reach that
goal. [21] On January 10, 2001, Sanger proposed on the Nupedia mailing
list to create a wiki as a "feeder" project for Nupedia. [22]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Launch and early growth

The domains wikipedia.com (redirecting to wikipedia.org ) and
wikipedia.org were registered on January 12, 2001, [23] and January
13, 2001, [24] respectively, and Wikipedia was launched on January 15,


...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems deet is None, check it before loop

```
deet = soup.find('h3', text = headers[iteri]) # None returned
```